# Spring Data: Query list of string annotated with @ElementCollection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

If I have an entity with this structure:

```
@Entity
public class RecipeRaw {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    List<String> listOfIngredients=new LinkedList<String>();
```

and I want to get a list containing all ingredients that contains the word X in it. How to do that?

for example if the word is beef, I want to get a list of ingredients like 'ground beef' , 'dried beef with salt' and so on.

I tried

```
@Query("select ings_temp from 
        (select rr.listOfIngredients ings_temp from RecipeRaw rr) ings 
        where ings LIKE '?1'")
```

But this throws an error. Is there any simple way to do this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by this

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT t FROM RecipeRaw rr JOIN rr.listOfIngredients t "
            + "WHERE t LIKE CONCAT('%', :ing_name, '%')")
    List<String> findIngredientsByLikeName(@Param("ing_name") String name);
```